# Using `pipeline` from `node:stream/promise` for multiple writable sources

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I have a `Readable` stream in object mode that I'm pushing data in, like this

```
const getReadStream = () => {
    const stream = new Readable({ objectMode: true, read: () => {} });

    const get = async (page = 1) => {
       const { data } = await client
           .request(...)
           .catch((error) => {
               stream.emit('error', error);
               return { data: undefined };
            });
    
       const results = parseFn(data);
    
       if (results.length > 0) {
           results.forEach((row) => stream.push(row));
           get(page + 1);
       } else {
           stream.push(null);
       }
    };
    
    get();

    return stream;
};
```

I would want to consume it into some `Writable` stream, like this

```
const consumeStream = async () => {

    const readableStream = getReadStream();

    const pipeline1 = pipeline(
        stream,
        transform1,
        transform2,
        someWritableStream,
    );

    if (!certainCondition) {
        return pipeline1;
    }

    const writeStream2 = new Writable({
        objectMode: true,
        write: (rows: any[], _, callback) => {
            somePromise(rows).then(() => callback());
        },
    });

    const pipeline2 = pipeline(
        stream,
        transform3,
        transform4,
        writeStream2,
    );

    return Promise.all([pipeline1, pipeline2]);
};
```

My question is, in the case where `consumeStream` proceed with `pipeline2` , is it the correct way to implement multiple writable stream with only 1 readable stream (as the number of objects processed by `pipeline1` = the number of objects processed by `pipeline2`. And if it is not, what is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have issues with the original stream data being already in progress or potentially ended by the time you start your second pipeline.

If you use a [PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/stream.html#class-streampassthrough) stream to duplicate data coming off of the original, then your method will work.

Here's a little script that demonstrates

```js
#!/usr/bin/node

const { promises: fs,
        createReadStream,
        createWriteStream } = require('node:fs'),
             { setTimeout } = require('node:timers/promises'),
 { PassThrough,
   promises: { pipeline } } = require('node:stream'),
                     assert = require('node:assert');

const srcFile = '/tmp/foobar',
      sinkFile1 = '/tmp/foobarSink1',
      sinkFile2 = '/tmp/foobarSink2';

async function mkSrc() {
  for(let i =0; i< 1000; i++) {
    if(i)
      await fs.appendFile(srcFile,'foobar\n');
    else
      await fs.writeFile(srcFile,'foobar\n');
  }
}

function getReadableStream() {
  return createReadStream(srcFile);
}

function getWritableStream(file) {
  return createWriteStream(file);
}

async function chkIt() {
  let chk1 = await fs.readFile(sinkFile1,'utf8'),
      chk2 = await fs.readFile(sinkFile2,'utf8');
  assert.equal( chk1, chk2);
}

async function test1() {
  await mkSrc();
  let stream = getReadableStream();
  let prom1 = pipeline( stream, getWritableStream(sinkFile1));
  await setTimeout(1000);
  let prom2 =  pipeline(stream, getWritableStream(sinkFile2));
  await Promise.all([prom1,prom2]);
  try { 
    await chkIt();
    console.log('Not using passthrough results in same stream data');
  }
  catch(err) { console.error('Not using passthrough results in different stream data') }
}

async function test2() {
  await mkSrc();
  let stream = getReadableStream();
  let passthrough = new PassThrough();
  stream.pipe(passthrough);
  let prom1 = pipeline( stream, getWritableStream(sinkFile1));
  await setTimeout(1000);
  let prom2 = pipeline(passthrough, getWritableStream(sinkFile2));
  await Promise.all([prom1,prom2]);
  try { 
    await chkIt();
    console.log('Using passthrough results in same stream data');
  }
  catch(err) { console.error('Using passthrough results in different stream data') }
}


async function main() {
  await test1();
  await test2();
}
main();
```

The results printed are

```
Not using passthrough results in different stream data
Using passthrough results in same stream data
```

So in your case you would do something like

```js
let stream = getStreamSomehow(),
    passthrough;
if(conditionChk) {
  passthrough = new Passthrough();
  stream.pipe(passthrough);
}
let pipeline1 = pipeline(stream,...);
if(!conditionChk)
  return pipeline1;
let pipeline2 = pipeline(passthrough,...);
doOtherStuff();
return Promise.all([pipeline1,pipeline2]);
```